# T SQL Cursor Returning Empty Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am building a cursor in T-SQL that will loop through each database and set variables that will then be placed into a table. The query completes successfully but the `#SaaS` table is empty. Printing the SQL shows that the correct database is being used depending on the select in the variable assignment. The cursor does fetch two columns from the `#dbNames` table as I use different databases depending on the variable. When I look at the `#dbNames` table the columns do contain nulls since the query spans multiple instances SQL servers so for example the `#dbNames` table looks like this:

```
ServerName | dbName         | dbName2
-------------------------------------
sql.inst1  | wfa00Reporting | null
sql.inst1  | null           | wfa00System
sql.inst1  | wfa01Reporting | null
sql.inst1  | null           | wfa01System
sql.inst2  | wfa02Reporting | null
sql.inst2  | null           | wfa02System
```

I am not sure what I am missing here since there is no error. Why is the `#SaaS` table empty upon completion of query?

SQL:

```
/* start */

begin try
DROP TABLE #SaaS
end try
begin catch
end catch
begin try
DROP TABLE #dbNames
end try
begin catch
end catch
DECLARE
         @prefix nvarchar(50) =  'WFA'

/**
* Create 2 temp tables for processing
*/
CREATE TABLE #dbNames (dbName NVARCHAR(255)
                        , dbName2 NVARCHAR(255))

CREATE TABLE #SaaS (dbName NVARCHAR(255)
                    , varA NVARCHAR(255)
                    , varB NVARCHAR(255))

/**
* Get the databases - all for now
*/
INSERT INTO #dbNames(dbName, dbName2)
SELECT CASE WHEN [name] LIKE '%Reporting' THEN [name] END as dbName
        , CASE WHEN [name] LIKE '%System' THEN [name] END as dbName2
FROM SYS.DATABASES 
WHERE State = 0 

/**
* A few variables for the Database list cursor
*/
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(255)
      , @dbName2 NVARCHAR(255)
      , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

/**
* get the values, only from ACA instances
*/
DECLARE EachDatabase CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT distinct [dbName],
        [dbName2]
 FROM #dbNames

OPEN EachDatabase 
FETCH NEXT FROM EachDatabase INTO @dbName, @dbName2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN

  SET @sql = '
                    DECLARE @varA AS nvarchar(255), @varB AS NVARCHAR(255)

                    SET @varB = (
                                        SELECT customerName
                                        FROM ' + @dbName2 + '.User.SystemSettings
                                        )

                    SET @varA = (
                                    select top 1 varA
                                    from
                                    ' + @dbName + '.eUser.tablecol
                                    WHERE varA >= 1/1/2018
                                    )

                    --REPORT STATUS

                    insert into #SaaS ( DBName
                                        , varA
                                        , varB
                                        )
                    select ''' + REPLACE(@dbName,'Reporting','') + '''
                            , @varA
                            , @varB
            '

  exec(@sql)

  FETCH NEXT FROM EachDatabase INTO @dbName, @dbName2
END

CLOSE EachDatabase
DEALLOCATE EachDatabase
-----------------------------------------End Table for SaaS

SELECT *
from #SaaS
order by dbName

/* end */
```

Comment: You should wrap this in a `try catch` and see if it works as you think it does, I know one thing I see that I've encountered as a problem, you can't have comments inside of a `dynamic sql statement`, so try removing `--Report STATUS` from your `SET @sql`

Comment: If any of your columns are null for @dbName then the entire SQL string will be null, try putting ISNULL(@Dbname, '')  first.

Plus you have so many try/catch at top of the script but your not doing anything in the catch, you shouldnt need that many, and put an if check instead of try/catch to see if the table exists, then drop (it will stop the error you are probably getting thus the reasy for all the try/catches)

Comment: Whenever you do dynamic you should ALWAYS select or print the dynamic sql string before executing it to ensure it is correct.

Comment: @brad So since there are `NULL` 's in `#dbNames` is this why the `#SaaS` table is empty? I just want to make sure as I will need to then find a different approach because ISNULL requires a replacement value and in this case `@dbNames` selects the database name and leaving this empty or using any other value would cause the `set @varA` to fail..

Comment: Yes when building out a string if you add a null value to any part of the string concat, the entire string is null, so if one of your dbnames has null, your entire dynamic sql will be a null value.  You may be able to do this since it is dynamic sql ISNULL(@dbname, 'NULL')  then null text will be just the keyword null in your dynamic sql.  try putting a print statement in your loop and see if that works (also you wouldnt need a cursor to do this, just a loop

Comment: @Brad Thanks for pointing out the over all issue with the SQL given the `NULL` values. Adding `ISNULL(@dbName, 'NULL')` failed the `set varA` as the `from` printed out `NULL..eUser.tablecol` which is not a schema in each server.database. It appears I will need to construct a `#dbNames` temp table without `NULL` values before I pass it into the cursor fetch. I am going to leave this open and update it with the correct SQL in case it is useful to anyone.

Comment: Yea then it sounds like a data issue you need to resolve to get your script to work, but eliminating the null at start should be easy in your select for the cursoer just do where dbname is not null (and same for all the columns)

Comment: @brad Thanks again. I posted the answer that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here as pointed out by @brad was that the temp table #dbNames contained NULL values. Here is the updated SQL that allowed me to not only receive the output I was looking for but also create a temp table without null values from different databases on different SQL instances to pass into the cursor. There may be a 'better' way but this solved my issue.

SQL:

```
/* start */

begin try
DROP TABLE #SaaS
DROP TABLE #dbNames
DROP TABLE #dbNamesCol1
DROP TABLE #dbNamesCol2
DROP TABLE #dbNamesALL
end try
begin catch
end catch
DECLARE
         @prefix nvarchar(50) =  'WFA'

/**
* Create 5 temp tables for processing
*/
CREATE TABLE #dbNames (dbName NVARCHAR(255)       --will hold the initial database names.
                        , dbName2 NVARCHAR(255))

CREATE TABLE #dbNamesCol1 (db NVARCHAR(255)         --holding table
                            , dbName NVARCHAR(255)) --will remove null values and be the fetch column for @dbName

CREATE TABLE #dbNamesCol2 (db NVARCHAR(255)         --holding table
                            , dbName2 NVARCHAR(255))--will remove null values and be the fetch column for @dbName2

CREATE TABLE #dbNamesAll (db NVARCHAR(255)          --Final table for dbName and dbName2 without NULL values
                          , dbName NVARCHAR(255)    --will join on db
                          , dbName2 NVARCHAR(255))  --Cursor will fetch from this final table

CREATE TABLE #SaaS (dbName NVARCHAR(255)            -- Output Table
                    , varA NVARCHAR(255)
                    , varB NVARCHAR(255))
/**
* Get the databases - all for now
*/
INSERT INTO #dbNames(dbName, dbName2)
SELECT CASE WHEN [name] LIKE '%Reporting' THEN [name] END as dbName
        , CASE WHEN [name] LIKE '%System' THEN [name] END as dbName2
FROM SYS.DATABASES 
WHERE State = 0 

/**
* Create TEMP Table that contains db names from two different
Databases. #dbNamesAll will be a join on db from 
#dbNamesCol1 and #dbNamesCol2 with no null values.
*/
INSERT INTO #dbNamesCol1 (db, dbName)
select REPLACE(dbName,'_Reporting',''), dbName
from #dbNames
WHERE dbName IS NOT NULL

INSERT INTO #dbNamesCol2 (db, dbName2)
select REPLACE(dbName2,'_System',''), dbName2
from #dbNames
WHERE dbName2 IS NOT NULL

INSERT INTO #dbNamesALL (db, dbName, dbName2)
select a.db,
       a.dbName,
       b.dbName2
from #dbNamesCol1 a
LEFT JOIN #dbNamesCol2 b ON b.db = a.db

/**
* A few variables for the Database list cursor
*/
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(255)
      , @dbName2 NVARCHAR(255)
      , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

/**
* get the values, only from ACA instances
*/
DECLARE EachDatabase CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT [dbName],
        [dbName2]
 FROM #dbNamesALL

OPEN EachDatabase 
FETCH NEXT FROM EachDatabase INTO @dbName, @dbName2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN

  SET @sql = '
                    DECLARE @varA AS nvarchar(255), @varB AS NVARCHAR(255)

                    SET @varB = (
                                        SELECT customerName
                                        FROM ' + @dbName2 + '.User.SystemSettings
                                        )

                    SET @varA = (
                                    select top 1 varA
                                    from
                                    ' + @dbName + '.eUser.tablecol
                                    WHERE varA >= 1/1/2018
                                    )

                    --REPORT STATUS

                    insert into #SaaS ( DBName
                                        , varA
                                        , varB
                                        )
                    select ''' + REPLACE(@dbName,'Reporting','') + '''
                            , @varA
                            , @varB
            '
  exec(@sql)

  FETCH NEXT FROM EachDatabase INTO @dbName, @dbName2
END

CLOSE EachDatabase
DEALLOCATE EachDatabase
-----------------------------------------End Table for SaaS

SELECT *
from #SaaS
order by dbName

/* end */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* start */

begin try
DROP TABLE #SaaS
end try
begin catch
end catch
begin try
DROP TABLE #dbNames
end try
begin catch
end catch
DECLARE
         @prefix nvarchar(50) =  'WFA'

/**
* Create 2 temp tables for processing
*/
CREATE TABLE #dbNames (dbName NVARCHAR(255)
                        , dbName2 NVARCHAR(255) NULL)

CREATE TABLE #SaaS (dbName NVARCHAR(255)
                    , varA NVARCHAR(255)
                    , varB NVARCHAR(255))

/**
* Get the databases - all for now
*/
INSERT INTO #dbNames(dbName)
SELECT [name]
FROM SYS.DATABASES 
WHERE State = 0 
AND name LIKE '%Reporting'

UPDATE #dbNames
SET dbName2 = REPLACE(dbName, 'Reporting', 'System')
/**
* A few variables for the Database list cursor
*/
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(255)
      , @dbName2 NVARCHAR(255)
      , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

/**
* get the values, only from ACA instances
*/
DECLARE EachDatabase CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT distinct [dbName],
        [dbName2]
 FROM #dbNames

OPEN EachDatabase 
FETCH NEXT FROM EachDatabase INTO @dbName, @dbName2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN

  SET @sql = '
                    DECLARE @varA AS nvarchar(255), @varB AS NVARCHAR(255)

                    SET @varB = (
                                        SELECT customerName
                                        FROM ' + @dbName2 + '.User.SystemSettings
                                        )

                    SET @varA = (
                                    select top 1 varA
                                    from
                                    ' + @dbName + '.eUser.tablecol
                                    WHERE varA >= 1/1/2018
                                    )

                    --REPORT STATUS

                    insert into #SaaS ( DBName
                                        , varA
                                        , varB
                                        )
                    select ''' + REPLACE(@dbName,'Reporting','') + '''
                            , @varA
                            , @varB
            '

  exec(@sql)

  FETCH NEXT FROM EachDatabase INTO @dbName, @dbName2
END

CLOSE EachDatabase
DEALLOCATE EachDatabase
-----------------------------------------End Table for SaaS

SELECT *
from #SaaS
order by dbName

/* end */
```